# microservices A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have client application to use microservices and i am using below code to call microservices.

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())

```
            {
                var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(AttModel));
                var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                string url = "http://servicename.com:60003/xxx/yyy";
                HttpResponseMessage message = client.PostAsync(url, byteContent).Result;
                string response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (response != "")
                {
                    //lblInsert.Text = "Your values inserted successfully and the Transaction Title is : " + response;
                }
            }
```

When I am calling micro services from this code, it is returning below error.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.xx.yy.zz:60001

I kept timeout infinite also

```
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
```

after that i turned of firewalls as well but no use.

This microservice is working from swagger in same machine.

Please help anyone, thanks in advance!

Comment: `microservices` is just branding. That's just an HTTP call that times out for the reason explained in the error. Either the remote service is down, stuck, too busy. Or there's a firewall in the middle that prevents you from calling it. This isn't a request timeout. In this case the OS couldn't even contact the remote service, much less send a request to it.

Comment: Do you have access to that other service? Have you tried debugging *it*? Checked the logs? Why did you add both the WCF and Web API tags, is it implemented in one of those stacks? Try using Fiddler or any other debugging proxy to see what's actually going on between the two services. You can also configure System.NET to log network events down to the socket level, by enabling switches in web.config

Comment: And finally, *DON'T* use `.Result` or `.Wait()` to block the thread. Make your method `async` by changing its return type to `async Task` and use `await` to actually await the asynchronous call without blocking. You should write  eg `var message = await client.PostAsync(url, byteContent);`

Comment: PS: your code tries to connect to `servicename.com:60003` while the error complains about `10.xx.yy.zz:60001`. Are you sure *this* is the code that throws?

Comment: I dont have access to that service,i will put await and async task and then i will try tq

Comment: You'll still get a timeout if you try to access the wrong port.

Comment: BTW you *don't* need to convert a JSON string to bytes either. Use a StringContent payload instead of `ByteArrayContent`. *DON'T* use the deprecated JavascriptSerializer. Even Web API uses JSON.NET. Finally, to check for success check the *StatusCode* of the response, not whether the response body is empty. Nothing guarantees that the response will contain anything more than the status code

Comment: I manually typed the port that is not the problem

Comment: Are you *sure*? 60003 isn't the same port as 60001. This would also explain why you didn't get a DNS timeout - System.Net was able to resolve the address but couldn't find anything to connect on 60001

Comment: Have you tried instantiating the HttpClient without "using"? 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8...
...